# How to get id of the tweet

Tags: twitter

I have set of tweet and their user name and want to get the their ID. Due to limitations of search API of twitter I cannot use it. Also the topsy.com doesnt  shows all the results.

Comment: Do you want to fetch the user or tweet id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the lookup method of the REST API https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friendships/lookup for get all the info of the tweet. Moreover if u got the screenName of the twitter users, u got the ID, because u can use both for identify the twitter users

Answer (score 19):

The tweetid can be fould on the url after you click on the tweet. 
Example:
https://twitter.com/RealHughJackman/status/**759043035355312128**