# Twitter API Get Tweet ID

Tags: api, twitter, oauth

I'm using an auto poster to post news stories to the Twitter account using the Twitter API 1.1.

I have a slight problem though... If there is something wrong with the news story and it is deleted, I need to be able to delete the tweet automatically.

To do this, I thought that if I can get the ID of the tweet and store it in the database, I could delete it this way, but I can't seem to get the ID of the actual tweet as it tweets if that makes sense? The best way I could find was to use the API to search the Twitter account and get the latest tweet, but there's a risk that the latest tweet is not the actual tweet.

I had a look through the API documentation and there's nothing that I can see that enables you to return the tweet ID. I also looked on here, this was the closest I got: [How to get id of the tweet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298994/how-to-get-id-of-the-tweet) But again, it searches rather than returns the specific ID.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384588/twitter-api-get-tweets-with-specific-id This post solves what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can POST your tweets to the [post/statuses/update](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update) endpoint.

You can then read ID as `id_str` in the response dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node.js, you could use

```
    var params = {status:"This is a dummy tweet to get the current tweet ID. Time:" + currTime};
    client.post('statuses/update', params, function(error, tweets, response){
  if (!error) {
    console.log(tweets.id);
    tweetid = tweets.id;

  }
});
```